# SQL View select data from two fields and combine into one

Tags: sql

I have one table that has two fields - ID1 and ID2
ID1 can be blank, ID2 is always populated.

I'd like to create a view that contains one field. This field would be the data from ID2 unless ID1 has a value in which case I need it to be ID1.

Coalesce doesn't work for me as ID1 isn't null.

All advice greatly received!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever "blank" means, if it's not `NULL`, can be expressed in a `CASE` condition:

```
CASE WHEN ID1 = 'blank' THEN ID2 ELSE ID1 END
```

Where `ID1 = 'blank'` is whatever your condition is.

Comment: CASE seems to work best for me - many thanks for all replies!

Comment: Since this is the accepted answer I think it's worth re-inforcing the point that if ID1 is NULL then you'll get NULL here, unless you add OR ID1 IS NULL

Comment: But the Question includes the phrase "ID1 isn't null" - the OP has explicitly ruled out a `NULL` scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Depending what exactly 'blank' means in this context, but if blank meant empty string or whitespace only:

Remove spaces from ID1 if it's possible for that column to contain whitespace that you want to still treat as blank by doing:

```
LTRIM(ID1)
```

Then you can make it `NULL` if it equals empty string by doing:

```
NULLIF(TRIM(ID1), '')
```

Then you can `COALESCE()` that with the ID2 column like this:

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(TRIM(ID1), ''), ID2)
```

If ID1 is always 'something' or '' (empty string) then you just need `NULLIF(ID1,'')`  which will return NULL if ID1 = an empty string

Original response, which is daft as it trims twice!

<strike>'[ID] = COALESCE(NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(ID1)), ''), ID2)'</strike>

Comment: TY @Andriy M - I just wasn't sure if blank == '', or if it might also be '_' or '__________'  (where _ represents whitespace)  Ah yes I did fail a bit there, of course you only need one TRIM if the whole string is whitespace.

Comment: Oops, my bad, I should have been more specific. What I meant was you didn't need to trim the string at all. Even if it was a series of spaces, it would still match an empty string. [Here's an illustration.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/2157)

Comment: Well I never...you really do learn something new every day!  Cheers.  Also, that SQL Fiddle looks pretty darn good too!

Answer (score 1):

```
select case when ID1 = '' then ID2 else ID1 end from MyTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT CASE ID1 = '' THEN ID2 ELSE ID1 END CASE FROM ...
```